# Filter the query and refresh the recycler view using firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(

            Product.class,
            R.layout.product_row,
            ProductViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ProductViewHolder viewHolder, Product model, int position) {

            Log.d(TAG, "loading view " + position);
            final String product_id = getRef(position).getKey();
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getName());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent productDetailIntent = new Intent();
                    productDetailIntent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ProductDetailActivity.class);
                    productDetailIntent.putExtra("product_id", product_id);
                    Log.d(TAG + " product_id", product_id);
                    startActivity(productDetailIntent);
                }
            });

            Log.d(TAG, "finish loading view");
        }
    };

    mProductList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

The above is the code that I use to get the data from the firebase realtime database. How can I change the query (mDatabase in my code) and refresh the recyclerview to filter the data? How to set a new adapter? Please give me some helps.Thank you.

Comment: Are you essentially saying that you want to load the results of a new query into the same RecyclerView after its adapter has already been set?

Comment: @DougStevenson I have Firebase RV with a list of items, and I need to filter the data when I use "search" item in the RV, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(

        Product.class,
        R.layout.product_row,
        ProductViewHolder.class,
        mDatabase.orderByChild("KeyName").equalTo("Value") //add this line 
)
 mProductList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
  firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // also add this line
```

Comment: But what if I have recyclerview in my fragment and I need to use search/filter option thru mainactivity?

Answer (score 0):

Set query in your database...

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductViewHolder>(

            Product.class,
            R.layout.product_row,
            ProductViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase.orderByChild("KeyName").equalTo("Value")

    )
```

Comment: How can I put it into the Recycler view and refresh it if I have already created one?

Comment: you need to set in adapter...check my updated answer

Comment: so I need to set the firebaseRecyclerAdapter and setAdapter again. But how to refresh it?